# Carry Sass variables through the Assets Pipeline, Rails 3.1 rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I recently branched one of my Rails 3.0 projects with the 3.1 rc1 to try the new assets pipeline. I've been using Sass in the project before going 3.1 so I've been setting up some variables and functions in a separate configure file and let all my other sass files import that one file at the first line.

This has been working out great to not repeat some color codes and general geometry through in the stylesheets. Problem is now with the new Assets Pipeline is that as I've understood it converts the ".css.sass" files to raw css before appending it to the rest of the code.

So if i specify, in my "application.css":

```
/*
 *= require ./configure
 *= require ./what_ever_other_files_i_want_to_import
*/
```

I get errors like:

```
Sass::SyntaxError
    Undefined variable: "$interactive".
```

When i try to access the file from: `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sass supports [Partials](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials). That way you can include your separate configuration in __configuration.sass_ and reference it with

```
@import "configuration";
```

from your main sass-file.

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the line (if you use SCSS syntax)

Comment: Thank you, this is how i solved the problem in the meanwhile. I have noticed, using Sass built in partials instead of the sprockets:

`/*= require ./file.css.sass */`

Will not compile the Sass files until your root (application.css.sass) is touched/saved/updated. This drastically slows down my worksflow.

What else is that @import seems to have troubles working when adding **.erb** at the end of file name to access the assets pipeline with the **assets_path** helper method.

Comment: I found the same issue as Philip. Even when using partials, if you add `.erb` to the file names, the variables don't get carried over and you have to import the partial on every file where you want to use them (instead of on a "master" one like I was doing before).

Comment: I'm just trying to figure this stuff out myself, but I believe you should add a depend_on directive to your manifest for any partials you @import.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I found out that SASS variables are be page specific.

If you want to carry your variables across all files, remove the 
`*= require_tree .` line from your application.css.scss file and replace it with the `@import "layout.css.scss";` directive to manually import each sass file.

Yes you have to @import each file

Comment: Its not working for me. I added the file that contains variable as @import 'layout.scss' inside application.css. But still If I dont import this file inside anotherfile.scss, its throwing undefined variable error.