# Asset pipeline sass import not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm using sass imports to handle most of my styles for our rails 3.2 app. My application.css.scss file looks like this:

application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./vendor
 *= require admin
 */
```

admin.css.scss

```
// Reset
@import "global/reset";

// General Variables
@import "admin/general/_variables";

// Main Elements
@import "admin/general/_typography";

// Layout
@import "global/_layout";
@import "admin/general/_gridset";

// Modules
@import "admin/modules/_table";
@import "admin/modules/_forms";
@import "admin/modules/_buttons";

// Styles
@import "admin/_style-clean";
@import "admin/_style-images";

// Features
@import "admin/features/features";
```

Error message: Sass::SyntaxError - Undefined variable: "$body-bg".
  (in /var/www/apps/dev_wbs/releases/20130624191222/app/assets/stylesheets/admin/_style-clean.css.scss)

_variables.css.scss (imported) contains $body-bg, and it is referenced in _style-clean.css.scss

I originally had this in the sass syntax, but every time we push to the dev server, we get an error of Sass::SyntaxError - Undefined variable: "$body-bg". The variable is declared in the variables file, and the error comes from the _style-clean scss file. I've dropped this variable into the style-clean file, but then I get another variable error, but it refers to one in the typography file, which is above the style-clean, making me think somehow that the assets are being pre-compiled and then added.

I'd like to go back to using sass syntax, but both scss and sass throw variable errors.

All individual files are currently in the format of: _variables.css.scss.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline relies on `application.css` to tell it what files to include. Changing it to SASS probably wouldn't allow that to work.

Also, your application.css needs to tell Ruby where to look for files:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include     all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

If you put the code you pasted in your question into a new file like global.css.scss and recreate the `application.css` in `/app/assets/stylesheets/` you should be off to the races both with the above code and SASS styles as well.

Comment: Oops, I left that off the top of my clip. I have the require self, but not the tree, because I don't want the application.css to precompile all of the assets, I would rather specify the order, as well as use all the great sass features in one file instead of in all of them.

Comment: In this case, its better to separate them. It makes the files easier to edit, harder to screw up as more developers join the project.

Comment: I've added it to a separate file, so now I have a plain application.css.scss file that has:

    /*
     *= require_self
     *= require ./admin
     */

But I'm still getting the variable error when pushing to dev (sorry, forgot I can't nest code in this)

Comment: `application.css` is important. Rails doesn't consider `.css.scss` as a manifest file by default.

Comment: update your question with the new code and the full error message please. IF you can include/highlight the line that the error pertains to, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Rob I updated the file structure! @meagar I've used it as application.css with this same structure but still got the variable error, so I changed it to .css.scss to do the imports directly

Comment: see if this helps now then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162468/carry-sass-variables-through-the-assets-pipeline-rails-3-1-rc1?rq=1

Comment: Rob, that's what I was doing with the original, importing all of my partials into one file, and now with this version, importing them all and then requiring that one main file

Comment: @RobAllen it almost seems like a problem with the dev server compiling assets differently than locally (because it works perfect there). Would you know if I need to change something in my application.rb file?

Comment: Hang on. I'm looking at the SASS docs as I don't think this Rails issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32294/discussion-between-spentacular-and-rob-allen)